# How do I control the time of the movie= parameter when overlaying video with video?

Tags: ffmpeg, filter, time

The following command overlays `main.mp4` with `talkingHead.mp4`.

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i main.mp4 -vf "movie=talkingHead.mp4, scale=400:-1 [inner]; [in][inner] overlay=main_w-(overlay_w+10): main_h-(overlay_h+10) [out]" out.mp4
```

It works fine when the videos are of the same length.
But assuming that `talkingHead.mp4` is 10 seconds long and `main.mp4` is 100 seconds long..

**1.** How do I overlay `main.mp4` with `talkingHead.mp4` only after the 5 seconds of `main.mp4`?

**2.** How do I make the right bottom corner disappear after `talkingHead.mp4` has finished? Right now `talkingHead.mp4` just freezes after 10 seconds.

P.S. I'm that there are `-ss` and `-t` but I cannot figure out their proper place in the command.